# How to make bitcoin payment button on a web page launch android wallet app

Tags: android, html, bitcoin

How do I make a Bitcoin payment button on a web page launch an Android wallet app such as Blockchain.info's wallet, passing the address and the amount to be paid to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `bitcoin:` URI with the `amount` parameter. For example:

```
bitcoin:175tWpb8K1S7NmH4Zx6rewF9WQrcZv245W?amount=12.3
```

See the [BIP 21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki) for a specification of this URI scheme.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just tested it exactly what I need.